# Problem retreiving null on nullable bool with default value through dapper [contrib]

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-contrib

This might be a bit of an edge case, and maybe I'm wrong in my understanding of how default values work in this case.

I have an issue where the below property is always returned as *true* even if it's *null* in the db. I guess this is due to the default value, but default values shouldn't override what's in the db - or so I thought.

Part of model..

```
public bool? SolvedByCalldesk { get; set; } = true;
```

Part of Dapper.Contrib-call..

```
...
var returnTask = connection.GetAsync<T>(id);
//caching here
result = await returnTask;
...
```

I've verified that the DB-record in question is *null*, but "result" returns it as *true*. Is this a problem with me, dapper or just how it works with default values on nullable types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response to this issue on [Dappers github](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/1168):

> It is indeed behaving as intended. You can use a constructor approach
>   instead if you want to override the behavior (just have a constructor
>   that matches the columns you're pulling back) if you want complete
>   control here :)

So any *null* in the database would use the default value in the model, rather than the database value (even if record existed and *null* is a valid value for the property/field).

It makes sense why it's handled like this, but at the same time it's not totally correct i.m.o.